# How do the coefficients from a model with an orthogonal polynomial predictor work?

Tags: r, statistics, polynomials

I have a model that I'm working with that uses a 2nd order orthogonal polynomial as a predictor using the R function poly(). I like the fit that it produces and the fact that it avoids the issue of multicollinearity that specifying X and I(X^2) as separate predictors creates. What I don't get is how to use my prediction equation, or more specifically, why predictions made by predict() don't match those from the prediction equation.

See example below:

```
library("tidyverse", "data.table", "tibble")

# Generate some data
set.seed(123)
dataset <- data.frame(x = sample(5:15, 100, replace = TRUE),
                      y = rnorm(100, 0, 1))

# Fit model with orthogonal polynomial predictor
model1 <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2), data = dataset)

# Store Coefficients in a DF
coefs <- summary(model1)$coefficients %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "Coefficient")

# Store values of orthogonal polynomial
polyX <- poly(sort(unique(dataset$x)), 2)

# Predictions
predict(model1, newdata = data.frame(x = 5))

# Predictions according to my coefficients/prediction equation
coefs$Estimate[coefs$Coefficient == "(Intercept)"] + 
  coefs$Estimate[coefs$Coefficient == "poly(x, 2)1"] * polyX[1, 1]+ 
  coefs$Estimate[coefs$Coefficient == "poly(x, 2)2"] * polyX[1, 2]
```

Why does predict() give me a prediction of -0.18 while the equation gives me -0.45?

I'm sure there is some linear algebra piece of the puzzle that I'm missing.

Thank you.

Comment: @李哲源, could you elaborate on that? I'm using the 1st row of the polyX matrix, which corresponds to the lowest value of x, which is 5.

Comment: I suggest you be patient and read the linked answer. The problem is with the construction of orthogonal polynomial, which is summarized by the **coef** parameter of `poly`. The first time you call `poly` in `lm`, such parameter is set. When you later make prediction you have to provide this **exact** info to `poly` or you get inconsistency.

Comment: aha, I see. The values of polyX generated only on the unique values of data$x are not the same as those generated by doing poly(data$x, 2).